# Flutter: how to extract the object of the future in order to work with it as with an ordinary object?

Tags: flutter, http, future

I want to extract the future object from the http request so that I can use it as a regular object in the widget. How can I achieve this? (abstract code example below)

```
class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
  Data? _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _loadData() async {
    await Service.getData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _data = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //further use of the _data variable
  }
}
```

In this case i'll have lateInitialization Error. In general, I would like to hear brief recommendations for working with future objects with explanations. Thanks

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: The recommended thing is that the object that will be rendered is never a nullable one, that is, you have to have a default object with default values. You will change this object if your request is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when working with `Future`'s within the `build` method, we use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) is a video from the Google team on how to use it.

In your example:

In the `_loadData()` function:

```
Future _loadData() async {
  await data = Service.getData();
    return data;
}
```

In the `build` method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _loadData(), 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text("data exists");
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error as String);

          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
       
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You could also .'then()' a future and setstate to update a state variable that comes from it, yeah?

Comment: @aolsan you can use `then()` but here I'm using `async`/`await` which is a shorthand for `.then`. Also, since we're using Future Builder, you can update the variable there